# Which homebrew package for "LWP::Protocol::https not installed" on macOSX?

Tags: macos, homebrew, fasta, dna-sequence, ncbi

I'm trying to download a fasta file from NCBI with the following perl-based pipeline:

```
esearch -db nuccore -query "\"\(internal transcribed spacer 1\"[All Fields] AND \(300[SLEN] : 600[SLEN]\)\) NOT \"uncultured Neocallimastigales\"[porgn] NOT \"bacteria\"[Filter]" \ | efetch -format fasta -mode text > ./Desktop/NCBI_ITS1_DB_raw.fasta
```

But I keep getting **501 Protocol scheme 'https' is not supported (LWP::Protocol::https not installed)**

To install this, other pages suggested using `sudo apt-get` or `sudo yum` scripts, but apt-get and yum are not recognized on macOSX. Others suggested using homebrew, but again apt-get and yum are currently not homebrew packages.

Simply, which homebrew package or script can allow me to download this fasta file?